# WooCommerce Force SSL Creates 404

Tags: wordpress, ssl, woocommerce, cpanel

So, I've read a few articles/blogs on this issue, but here's mine:

When I activate "Force SSL" in Woocommerce settings, I get a 404 on any pages that have HTTPS.

I have a dedicated SSL certificate on my domain, and that is no problem. It is not caused by plugins, I have tested that.

I've heard that you need to modify the "default-ssl" file on your server. You apparently need to modify your htaccess file to match the settings of your "default-ssl" file. If this is not accessible on a shared hosting server, then this is not a viable solution for anyone who doesn't have a VPS or access to root level SSH.

I've also been told that you need to reset your WP permalink settings to default. This is bad for SEO and quite frankly, an "I failed" non-solution.

If there is a way to get around this problem that can be fixed by having access only to cPanel and FTP, then answer this question. If it is definitely not possible via these means, please tell me why.

Comment: Have you changed your Site URL and WordPress URL in your WordPress Dashboard? Also, have you simply gone to the `Permalinks` section of the Dashboard an clicked `Update` (without actually changing anything)?

Comment: Modifying those through the WP Dashboard isn't even possible. I assume you mean "WP settings"?

Comment: Just tried it. Thanks. That just broke the whole site.

Comment: No, I mean the WordPress dashboard, under the settings menu. That didn't break the whole site; something else broke it (i.e. the root of the problem). The correct Site and WordPress URLs should contain `https`, if your entire site is under SSL (which it should be).

Comment: Do I need to change my htaccess or something then?

Comment: I am testing on a subdomain, which gives me a not-secure icon in the address bar. Doubt this is causing the 404 though?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is something that is going to benefit others, but if you're on shared hosting, testing on a subdomain is a bad idea. Rather test on "www.yourdomain.com/testing/", as opposed to "testing.yourdomain.com". Don't ask me why, the nerdy reasons I will leave to the back-end guys who answer my questions with grammatically unintelligible questions and down-votes.

You can have custom domains on your Woocommerce site after all. Don't test on a subdomain.

Comment: your SSL won't cover a subdomain, so a subdomain purchased for "mysite.com" will cause an error on "sub.mysite.com" since it doesn't have an SSL.